# Creating a hollow rectangle with Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, recursion

I'm trying to figure out a way that I can create a rectangle with a hole between it using haskell as shown

```
Main > putStr (hollowedrectangle 4 5)

 *****
 *   *
 *   *
 *****
```

However, I know my code below implements topnbot row first, thus it currently returns a full starred line in the middle (topnbot). I'm trying to figure out what I need to change in my code so it gives the result above as opposed to the result below.

```
topnbot :: Int->String
topnbot x 
   | x <= 0 = ""
   | x == 1 = "*"++topnbot(x-1)
   | x > 0 = "*"++topnbot(x-1)

leftnright :: Int->Int->String
leftnright x y
   | y==1 = "*"
   | x < 0 = ""
   | x >= 0 = "*"++mid (y-1)
   where
    mid :: Int->String
    mid z
      | z <= 0 = ""
      | z == 1 = leftnright x z
      | z > 0 =  " "++mid (z-1)

hollowedrectangle :: Int->Int->String
hollowedrectangle a m 
  | m == 0 = topnbot m
  | a == 0 = ""
  | a < 3 = topnbot m
  | a >= 3 && m >= 3 = topnbot m ++"\n"++leftnright a m ++ "\n" ++hollowedrectangle (a-1) m
```

This results in

```
  Main > putStr (hollowedrectangle 4 5)
    *****
    *   *
    *****
    *   *
    *****
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is longer and more complicated than I like to read, so let me give you some hints:

First, write a function

```
replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]
```

that makes a list of the given length whose elements are all the given one. So

```
replicate 3 7 = [7,7,7]
replicate 4 'a' = "aaaa"
```

For efficiency, write `replicate` without using `++`. Test it for efficiency by typing

```
replicate (2^30) 'x' !! 10000
```

at the GHCi prompt. If you have time to blink before it spits out an answer, you've done something wrong.

Can you figure out how to use `replicate` and `++` to produce the top row, the bottom row, and one of the middle rows? Can you figure out how to use `replicate` to produce all of the middle rows?

P.S., the `replicate` function is available in the standard library, but you shouldn't look for it till you've written it.